# WaitForSingleObject and while loops in C/++

Tags: c++, mutex, waitforsingleobject

Here is the snippet:
prog1:

```
HANDLE hM;
hM = CreateMutexA(NULL,TRUE, "abc"); // I have to use TRUE otherwise WaitForSingleObject fails.. by design it wants to take ownership and w//o TRUE there is no owner anyway right? <<-- **check this please if its true**
...
```

prog2:

```
HANDLE hM;
hM = OpenMutexA(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS,NULL, "abc");
while(WaitForSingleObject(hM,INFINITE)) {
// do smthing
ReleaseMutex(hM);
hM = OpenMutexA(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS,NULL, "abc"); // In order to continue while loop but it doesnt rewind,
}
```

Issue> It won't make semi-infinite loop ... it enters once and thats it.

Purpose? To monitor activity of some process (if it crash I restart it), infinite loops are hitting my CPU hard and I cant use Sleep, I need to restart it asasp (well if some smart solution is possible via while(1) or for(;;) please post)

**UPDATE**

should be while(WaitForSingleObject(hM,INFINITE) == WAIT_ABANDONED){ ... }, I didnt copy correctly :).

It works once and then it won't wait again, is there a way to reset handle?

---

prog1:

```
HANDLE hM;
hM = CreateMutexA(NULL,TRUE, "abc");
```

prog2:

```
HANDLE hM;
hM = OpenMutexA(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS,NULL, "abc");
while(WaitForSingleObject(hM,INFINITE)) {    
ReleaseMutex(hM);
Sleep(1000);
CloseHandle(hM)
// do smthing like CreateProcess()
Sleep(1000);
hM = OpenMutexA(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS,NULL, "abc");
}
```

This way it works, if anyone wants to add something comment on this post.

Comment: Thats true :) but you have to be little bit experianced to go full Unicode

Comment: Just curious, what kind of experience would that require?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To detect process crash, you shouldn't bother with a mutex. Just wait on the process handle. Once the process exits, the handle will be signaled, and `WaitForSingleObject` will return.

If you're creating the process, you can get the process handle from the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` argument. Then, just use:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

do {
// create the process, passing pi as the last argument to CreateProcess
} while (WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE));
```

Note that the handle should be closed, you can figure out when.

---

Update - Given this is not an option, here's the problem in your code:

Say prog1 started successfully, and prog2 is now waiting for the mutex to be signaled. Then prog1 crashes, and prog2 gets to own the mutex. Given prog2's purpose is to relaunch prog1, I assume this is what happens in `// do smthing`. So now prog1 starts, and calls `CreateMutexA`. But prog2 might still be holding the mutex, and so prog1 only gets a handle to the existing mutex, but it doesn't actually own it. Now prog2 calls ReleaseMutex, and continues to a wait on a signaled mutex, which is not owned by prog1. The wait immediately returns with `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, and you get out of the `while`.

So, I think prog1's use of `CreateMutexA` is wrong here. You should instead create an un-owned mutex, and wait on it. This way, you'll ensure prog1's ownership of the mutex.

Comment: Actuall code isn't as simple as I posted it. Its kinda complex and yes I've used this but only solution for now is either Mutex or Shared Memory approach. So try to help on his eran.

Comment: Ok. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: OMG, that might work. Check this thread again please, Im so testing this like crazy now :).You want me to make if() in prog1 and wait there first, or to use FALSE flag on that single line?

Comment: Hmmm... There's still a race, though. If prog1 creates the mutex, then prog2 releases it and immediately gets to the wait before prog1 does, it'll still exit. Needs further thinking, you might have to use two mutexes.

Comment: I was suggesting you use a FALSE, followed by a WaitForSingleObject. But as said, there's still a race. Adding a Sleep(10000) in prog2, after the `ReleaseMutex` (in addition to the above) will probably "hide" the race, but it would be a patch, and not a perfect solution.

Comment: two mutex? damn, WaitForMultipleObjects... no way sir too complicated for me, if you have time knock yourself out :). However I had FALSE before and it didnt work completly so thats no go. I added Sleep between ReleaseMutex and CloseHandle but kept TRUE flag. Body of while is executed 2 times now instead of 1 but it doesnt exit like before so its something... I will continue to tweak and maybe bump here with updates

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4259/discussion-between-cat9-and-eran)

Comment: Using two synchronization objects is not that hard. Consider using a named [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655(v=vs.85).aspx): Have prog2 create it non-signaled after `ReleaseMutex` and wait on it, and have prog1 open and signal that event after it owns the mutex (i.e. after the call to WaitForSingleObject). This way, prog2 will get to the `while (WaitForSingleObject)` only after prog1 has secured ownership of the mutex.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with eran's point that you should just wait directly on the process handle.

As to why your code does not enter the `while` loop when you think it should that is easy enough to work out. The `while` loop terminates when `WaitForSingleObject` returns 0. That is when it returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, or in other words when it has acquired ownership of the mutex. That happens when the previous owner releases it.

Comment: Also, since you've taken the part of answering the actual question ;), it's worth mentioning the second call to `OpenMutexA` in prog2 is redundant. No reason to open an already opened mutex.

Comment: The second call is to "trick" while loop to restart itself and wait again which worked when I was dealing with OpenProcess and process handles from CreateProcess.

Comment: And I think its not WAIT_OBJECT_0 but WAIT_ABANDONED

Comment: `WAIT_ABANDONED` is non-zero and in that case the while condition would be satisfied. The only way for the while to terminate is when `WaitForSingleObject` returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0 == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reopen the mutex.
WaitForSingleObject takes ownership and ReleaseMutex releases the ownership, but the mutex stays open until you call CloseHandle.

Comment: I have tried that, ReleaseMutex + CloseHandle and then "stuff". At the end I would call again OpenMutexA. It wouldnt work as I want, it will enter while() and exit from it. Im opening mutex again only to trick while loop to continue but no dice, hope you understand.